# Is there any reason to major in physics if you're certain you will never do a Ph.D?

Tags: soft-question, education

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What sort of jobs do physics graduates with B.Sc/M.Sc get?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/what-sort-of-jobs-do-physics-graduates-with-b-sc-m-sc-get)

I've been told over and over again..."I would not major in physics unless you are looking to get a Ph.D." What is it that physics majors do with B.S./M.S. degrees? I'm currently studying engineering physics (though most of my courses lean toward engineering theory and not pure physics, really)

(Apologies in advance if the question is ill-posed or too subjective in its current form to meet the requirements of the FAQ; I'd certainly appreciate any suggestions for its modification if need be.)

Thanks, I'd greatly appreciate some responses

Comment: This is basically covered by your previous question. And anyway, this isn't the type of question that this site is really intended to address. It's fine if we get a _few_ instances of questions about "physicist life," but they're basically special cases.

Comment: *"I would not major in physics unless you are looking to get a Ph.D."* Bloody silly advice. If you're not planning on being anything in particular, then majoring in physics is just as "good for you" as any other major that you would take to get a "classical education". If you find it interesting go right ahead, but take some other stuff too. A university education is supposed to  give you breadth *and* depth. If you have a particular plan, *then* you worry about what your choice of major will or will not do for you.

Comment: dmckee's got it exactly right. As a college physics professor, I hear similar things from students' parents all the time. The fact is that people with undergraduate degrees in physics do *very* well in the job market.